# access all paypal transaction data

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

If I did not store the transaction ID on my server, how can I go about getting all of my transaction IDs?  I plan on using them to get all of the information for all of my transactions.  It would be great if this can all be done programatically and the solution is available to the public on github or somewhere else.

Comment: Have you looked at the Paypal API documentation?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII I see where you can use the transaction ID with the REST API but don't see how to iterate over transaction IDs in the paypal database: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#sale-transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of your transactions using the [TransactionSearch API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/).  Then you can get more details about any individual transaction using [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).

If you happen to be using PHP you may want to look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It will make these API calls very quick and easy for you.  In fact, [here's a sample of what the TransactionSearch result looks like from my library](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/TransactionSearch.php).

Scroll down and you'll see a SEARCHRESULTS section, which has all of the results parsed into an array nice and neat for you to work with.

Comment: thank you for your response - I just found the TransactionSearch API as well.